# Code works when i put javascript alert in between anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs on key tab press, it works fine when i put a javascipt alert in between the code, any kind of alert,if i remove the alert it stops working : my function

```
//Function to set the tab feture for focus to work properly on fields with autosuggestion(location and name)
function setFocusOnTab(name) {


    var focusElement = "";

    if(name == "name") {//For main contact field

        if ($("#email").is(":visible")) {
            $('#email').focus();
        }
    } else if(name == 'location_name') {//For main contact field
        $("#country").focus();
    } else {//For extra contact field


        var outputDataCurrentVal = name.lastIndexOf('record_');


        if(outputDataCurrentVal < 0) {

            //ADDTIONAL CONTACT TAB
            var outputDataCurrentName = name.lastIndexOf('_name_');
            if(outputDataCurrentName >= 0) {
                //Replacing the  name to get location name.
                locName = currentName.replace("_name_","_designation_"); 
                focusElement = locName;
            } else {

                var outputDataCurrentLoc = name.lastIndexOf('_location_');  
                if(outputDataCurrentLoc >= 0) {
                    //Replacing the location name to get country name.
                    countryName = name.replace("_location_","_country_"); 
                    focusElement = countryName;
                }
            }

        } else {


            //Extra CONTACT TAB
            var outputDataCurrentName = name.lastIndexOf('_name_');
            if(outputDataCurrentName >= 0) {
                //Replacing the  name to get location name.
                locName = currentName.replace("_name_","_location_"); 
                focusElement = locName;
            } else {

                var outputDataCurrentLoc = name.lastIndexOf('_location_');  
                if(outputDataCurrentLoc >= 0) {
                    //Replacing the location name to get country name.
                    countryName = name.replace("_location_","_country_"); 
                    focusElement = countryName;

                }
            }
        }



        $("#" + focusElement).focus();
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please define does not work. Do you get an exception? Weird results? No results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need something to halt your code, which is what `alert()` does.

You may need a callback instead.

Comment: yes i think so , thats why i put return false at the end.But that does not worked, but if put alert in place of return false it works.........very starnge to me.

Comment: In place of false? So you remove the false and make an alert? Try returning true is an option.

Comment: Well then give me upvotes ;) 
But good to hear a return true works, is the code called from an event (like a click), that could explain why it is not working when returning a false (this will cause the event to "stop").

Answer (score 1):

What *might* be happening with `alert()` is that calling it causes the current window to lose focus (as focus moves to the new pop-up dialogue box), and after it's finished it re-focuses the window. This will trigger focus and blur events which might confuse your script, and in Safari the window may not re-focus at all.

It's not clear to me what you are doing here... how are you attaching this code to a tab key event? What event is supposed to be cancelled by the `return false;`? If you are using `keypress`, then that simply won't get called for the Tab key in IE, Safari or Chrome. If you are using `keydown`, then cancelling the event won't prevent the tabbing in Opera. And what about Shift-Tab?

Reproducing/altering browser keyboard behaviour is *hard*: it's much better not to if there's any other way. For making controls like a drop-down suggester work you are probably much better off just setting the declarative `tabIndex` on the elements concerned and letting the browser work out how to sort out the tabs from there.

Answer (score 0):

I should write something on this post. I read so many blogs and post but couldn't get the right solution from anywhere else. Even in this post, I looked more detail and tried each of solution.

Finally reading the answer of bobince, I could figured out the solution. In my case, I have set the focus to another textbox ( not required type) and later when I finish my job, I set back focus to original one. So the morel story is we just need to set focus somewhere else from current element which actually done by alert and I have replaced that on by setting the focus on non required element.